# Is there any way to display comma separated list vertically in a single cell using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a list in one of the columns separated by comma and I want to display it vertically inside that cell to improve readability.

As an example -

```
               ID      VALUE
               2  ['(39,"nmo","omg",889)','(40,"jjj","kkk",880)']
               3  ['(41,"nmo","omg",889)','(42,"jjj","kkk",880)']
```

How I want to display it is:

```
                             ID       VALUE
                             2     39 nmo omg  889
                                   40 jjj kkk  880

                             3     41 nmo omg  889
                                   42 jjj kkk  880
```

Thank you.

Comment: please post your dataframe with column names and  minimum 2 rows

Comment: @pyd- sorry about that, done

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.set_index("ID")
df["VALUE"] = df["VALUE"].apply(
              lambda x: [" ".join(map(str, eval(i))) for i in eval(x)]
              )

df = df.explode("VALUE")

print(df)

ID  VALUE
    2     39 nmo omg 889
            40 jjj kkk 880
    3     41 nmo omg 889
          42 jjj kkk 880
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking to display ID 2 and 3 only once and I want both the values in a single cell

Comment: Remove resetindex and see